# Do I need a validator or RPC node in order to use Geyser?

Tags: web3.js, subscription, websocket

I want to use Geyser plugins but I need to know do I need a power full computer in order to run a validator or RPC node? if yes what are the hardware requirements ? The estimated requests per month is 20 million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run either a validator or an RPC node.

> You can see the requirements here:
> https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-reqs

(RPC nodes should have at least the h/w specs as that of a validator, more if need better performance)

On GCE something like this would work:

> GCE n2-standard-32 (32 vCPUs, 128 GB memory) instances with 2048 GB
> SSD

Given estimated requests per month ~20 million, you should be able to handle this with the bare minimum h/w requirements.