# Latency is RPC response and websocket

Tags: rpc, solana-cli, jsonrpc-api, websocket, api

I have a websocket which points at my wallet, And I also have a websocket setup to get the latest event on my wallet.

I have tried sending an airdrop from CLI tool : [link](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/2rLaoydqoP1TzMiTAx7usFk1s19LXbB5RJpCFaA4Feq532hgEWLqTn4fUR9uWRao6kP3r8GT9KhcRVELJgXH8gVc?cluster=devnet)

The moment the transaction has been finished is `15:33:36` but the moment data was received from the websocket is `15:33:53` which means 17s delay.

How can i reduce this delay to 1s or less ?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to reduce the delay beyond rpc limitations is to be running your own validator with Geyser hooked up. Still you might not hit 1s because of the way validators communicate.

You could also try other rpc providers but most will be hovering around that range. There's also confirmation levels to be aware of, just because your transaction's block was created at that time doesn't mean it was confirmed at that time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually I am thinking about using Geyser but as I asked in https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2532/do-i-need-a-validator-or-rpc-node-in-order-to-use-geyser I don't know the hardware requirements for such approach. 
And I must add that I tried using QuickNode which also has a delay of 10-15 seconds, and about the transaction confirmation is should say, I put a link with confirmation timestamp.